# Slower Internet speeds with USB ethernet adapter than card from motherboard

Tags: networking, usb, performance, internet, network-adapter

I'm having very weird performance issue with downloading files.

**Networking:**

- Huawei HG8240H router ( ISP ) - 1 Gbps FO link
- TP-Link Archer C6 AC1200 connected to that Huawei router with 1 Gbps
  port serving WiFi 5GHz

**Computers:**

- ASUS Zephyrus G14 ROG | Ryzen R9 5900HS | 32 GB RAM | USB3 ethernet additional
  adapters | MediaTek WiFi6 MT7921 built in | Windows 11 Pro | Windows
  Defender only
- Dell Latitude 5480 | I5-7440HQ | 32 GB RAM | Intel I219-LM built in LAN card | Intel Dual
  Band Wireless-AC 8265 WiFi built in | Windows 10 Pro | ESET AV
- PC Asrock Z87 Extreme 4 | I7-4700K | 16 GB RAM | Intel I217-V 1 Gbps LAN built in | Windows
  7 Pro | ESET AV ( almost 10 year old machine )

**USB3 ethernet adapters:**

- ASUS 2.5 Gbps C2500 USB RJ45 ( Realtek RTL8156 )
- Ugreen 1 Gbps USB RJ45 ( ASIX AX88179 )

Transfering in LAN or checking speedtest.net get **940+ Mbps** over **110 MB/s** ( for speedtest in most scenarios multisession ) on all computers.

**Issue:**

When I download something with USB3 ethernet adapters it's almost in all cases slower 2-8 times than downloading same file with PC with Intel ethernet card on motherboard. In some cases even downloading with WiFi is more stable and faster than with USB3 adapters.

Very often download is starting with good speed like 70-80 MB/s and constantly falling down even to 4-5 MB/s. For example WiFi starts slower and speed is nicely raising then it keeps good stable value like 40 MB/s ( I have 1200 ac ).

I have no idea why this is so wrong.

Here is example video:

USB Adapter: https://youtu.be/JZamlY7rY9s   ( verify how bad is after 40 s )

PC Download: https://youtu.be/HVai_LmFSdE   ( speed is almost constant )

**Tried:**

1. Removed ASUS C2500 device from Windows & checked 3 drivers - best is from Microsoft (2015 year ), worst are from Realtek (2020 year and 2022 year )
2. Tried to plug laptops directly into ISP router, different ports and different cables ( same cable as PC too ).
3. Changed USB ports for USB3 adapters - even USB-C with additional adapter ( Unitek ). Also tested it with PC.
4. Changed some settings in driver related to TCP Offload and Control Flow Mode Select: Passive / Agressive
5. Reseting network - Settings > Network & internet > Advanced network
   settings > Network reset
6. Used TCP Optimizer ( tuning) from
   https://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php
7. Tested different browsers. Edge, Chrome, Firefox, SRW Iron, Opera and wget.
8. Checked power/battery plans from silnet, normal, performance. No
   matter if it's plugged or not to power cord.
9. Plugged that USB3 adapter to PC - same problems.
10. Lowered MTU from 1500 to lower values like 1458, 1300 etc.
11. All computers have fast SSD drives capable of writing much more than 100 MB/s.
12. Checked different settings for registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters including TcpWindowSize ( values between 131072 and 16000000 ), GlobalMaxTcpWindowSize ( values between 131072 and 16000000 ) and Tcp1323Opts ( 0,1,3 ) - first I thought that it helped but I see that it's slowing down in some scenarios ( on PC it doesn't )
13. Changed Congestion Provider from CUBIC to CTCP.
14. Tested with Linux Lubuntu BootCD - **this one solves issue** - speeds are much higher and more stable, but I want to make it fast on Windows 11.

I discovered that if network latency is low like LAN or let's say 3-5 ms speeds are awesome ( over 100 MB/s ) no matter if I use adapter or normal ethernet card, but if it's something from larger distance like other country for example from Germany, Sweden etc. with latency 25+ ms speeds are much lower than with PC ethernet card. I know this might be related to TCP buffers but like I said I used optimized option in TCP Optimizer for that network cards.

**TCP Global :: Zephyrus**

*netsh interface tcp show global*

```
TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State          : enabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : normal     <<<<<<<<< enabled
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : default
ECN Capability                      : disabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
Initial RTO                         : 2000
Receive Segment Coalescing State    : disabled
Non Sack Rtt Resiliency             : disabled
Max SYN Retransmissions             : 2
Fast Open                           : enabled
Fast Open Fallback                  : enabled
HyStart                             : enabled
Proportional Rate Reduction         : enabled
Pacing Profile                      : off
```

**Congestion :: Zephyrus:**

*Get-NetTCPSetting | Select SettingName, CongestionProvider*

```
SettingName      CongestionProvider
-----------      ------------------
Automatic
InternetCustom   CUBIC
DatacenterCustom CUBIC
Compat           NewReno
Datacenter       CUBIC
Internet         CUBIC
```

**TCP Global & congestion :: PC**

```
Parametry globalne TCP
-------------------------------------------------------
Stan skalowania odbioru                        : enabled
Stan odciążania (technologia Chimney)          : disabled
Stan NetDMA                                    : disabled
Bezpośredni dostęp do pamięci podręcznej (DCA) : enabled
Poziom autodostrajania okna odbierania         : normal   <<<<<<<< enabled
Dostawca dodatkowej kontroli przeciążenia      : ctcp     <<<<<<<< different in Win7
Funkcja ECN                                    : disabled
Sygnatury czasowe RFC 1323                     : disabled
```

I changed **Congestion Provider** from **CUBIC** to **CTCP** - it didn't help.

```
The TCP global default template is internet

TCP Supplemental Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Minimum RTO (msec)                  : 300
Initial Congestion Window (MSS)     : 10
Congestion Control Provider         : ctcp
Enable Congestion Window Restart    : disabled
Delayed ACK timeout (msec)          : 40
Delayed ACK frequency               : 2
Enable RACK                         : enabled
Enable Tail Loss Probe              : enabled
```

Does anyone have idea what else I could check and how to solve this performance problems for laptop without built in ethernet card? It would be great to fix somehow that USB3 adapters. I could buy better WiFi6 router but this is not a preferred solution.

Nothing helps.

Comment: I would expect a performance degradation with a USB Ethernet adapter compared to a built-in adapter on the motherboard. Why are you expecting equal performance out of the USB adapter? A better WiFi 6 router will have zero impact on Ethernet performance

Comment: what does the current status of the USB to ethernet adapter say? Is it 1GBps or 100Mbps? I wonder if despite it being a 1GBps adapter if it has auto-negotiated a 100Mbps connection with your router instead.

Comment: @Ramhound because it's 2.5 Gbps and USB3 is 5 Gbps so why not?

Comment: @Mastaxx of course it's negotiating with 1Gbps :) and I'm getting speeds over 113 MB/s on both just in LAN or from close locations. Anyway seems problem is in drivers I'll do update in a minute.

Comment: @mike - The total bandwidth on the port is 5 Gbps without any EMI.  You are not going to get 5 Gbps in the real world outside of a lab. The speed of non-USB 3.2 Gen 2 Ethernet devices are typically pretty slow.  I am shocked a 2.5G adapter even exists that isn't USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-C.   Faster WiFi will have zero impact on your Ethernet performance.

Comment: @Ramhound yes but this should be able to handle just 1 Gbps traffic and it does. I did some tests now on latest drivers and I'm getting confused seems this issue might be related also to my ISP, path to destination or other random things. Now i'm getting for example (112 MB/s) average in 1 GB file from Internet ftp site on ASUS adapter.

Comment: This is completely random, I tested today I didn't change anything and it's again wrong, on PC which is right next to it speeds are always flawless. I'm loosing hope to solve this issue. :/

Comment: You could be facing heat-related problems. My (old) ASIX USB Ethernet adapter gets quite hot.

Comment: @DanielB no it's not heat issue. If I can download with 100+ MB/s how much I want in LAN or low latency locations ( same Country ). This only happen if something is in longer distance I change to WiFi and it's constant 40-45 M/s, on PC it's much better almost every scenario it's fast and stable. I have both USB adapters with ASIX and RTL same issue.

Comment: USB 3.0 ports have a latency almost 1000 times worse than PCIE 5.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the iperf tool to test instead of downloading from the Internet because there are too many uncertainties in the Internet

Comment: maybe if it was happening in every scenario You are right, but if I just run this Adapter on same laptop with Linux speeds are good, so it has to be something related to device drivers or special Windows network / TCP settings.