# Windows 11 got slower Internet speed than Ubuntu

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, network-adapter

My current network setup: 2x 1Gbps Internet from ISP and I did load balancing on my router. The connection speed between the router and my PC is 2.5Gbps, which should give me around 1.8Gbps download speed.

I can only get 800-900Mbps download speed on Windows 11. However, in Ubuntu (dual boot on the same desktop PC), I can reach 1800Mbps download speed.

What I have tested on my desktop:

- Windows 11 + PCIe 2.5Gbps NIC: 900Mbps
- Windows 11 + USB 2.5Gbps NIC: 900Mbps
- Ubuntu 22.04 + PCIe 2.5Gbps NIC: 1800Mbps
- Ubuntu 22.04 + USB 2.5Gbps NIC: 1800Mbps

On my laptop:

- Windows 11 + USB 2.5Gbps NIC: 800Mbps
- Ubuntu 20.04 + USB 2.5Gbps NIC: 1500Mbps

On my Macbook:

- macOS + USB 2.5Gbps NIC: 1800Mbps

I tried iperf3 between the router and my desktop (on Windows 11), and I got around 2.1Gbps, so I guess the link speed should be fine, but the internet speed is slow.

Specs:

- AMD Ryzen 3700X
- Asus Prime X570 Pro motherboard
- Realtek 8125B NIC (PCIe)
- Realtek 8152B NIC (USB)

Comment: Why don't you try SpeedTest or like to see what real world results are.

Comment: Hi, all the speed test results (except the iperf3 one) are obtained from speedtest.net .

Comment: Try updating the Windows 11 NIC drivers.

Comment: Hi, I tried both Microsoft default driver and latest Realtek driver, and disabled energy saving, enabled jumbo frame, none of them worked

Comment: I do not know. I have Windows 11 Pro here and WAN and LAN Speeds are excellent. No issues.

Comment: I have related problems with USB NIC Asus ( RTL8156 ) and Ugreen (ASIX 88179 ) can't fix this issue, internet ond Ubuntu is much faster than on W11 - especially it's not slowing down in time - keeps constant high speeds. Here is my case: https://superuser.com/questions/1729035/slower-internet-speeds-with-usb-ethernet-adapter-than-card-from-motherboard